# How to call a method from a certain Java thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Currently I am working on Java client/server chat app and got one question, I'll try to explain as clear as possible.

My server part keeps creating threads (`new ServerThread`) for each user who comes online:

```
while (isRunning) {
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    outputStreams.put(socket, dout);
    System.out.println (outputStreams.values());
    new ServerThread(this, socket); 
    window.newConnectionInfo(socket);// informace
}
```

I have a getter method in a *ServerThread* class, which I want to call from the certain *ServerThread* instance based on socket. But *ServerThread* class isn't assigned to any variable, so I don't know exactly how to call methods from it. Any solution on that?

Comment: If you need to call this on all server threads, I suggest you build a list of them and iterate over that when needed. If you need to call it on particular threads under certain circumstances, more information about your scenario is needed.

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Your `ServerThread` has a `run()` method, in which the flow of execution occurs.  You would call a method from there if you want to call "from" the thread.

Comment: Why don't you store a reference to each ServerThread after creating it. Insert it into a static hash map with the socket as key.

Comment: When you start the thread. It will run the method run() of the thread. In that method you have access to the instance of the thread using "this" so just call the getter method there. If the caller thread is different from the servicethread that you want to call its getter, you need to keep track of the created servicethreads somehow. For example using a list or a map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, you need to locate and find the thread you want to force call a method, that you would keeps every thread you create, I suggest you the Map you are using for keeping clients would be in < ServerThread ,DataOutputStream >, so here you have all threads now (and Scoket instance inside the ServerThread), okay and the answer.

okay first you need a method for signalling the target thread in the ServerThread, like this

```
class ServerThread{
public void forceToCall(Object o){//an object argument, would be void too, or an interface
    //do something, call someone
  }
}
```

then, so who is going to call this method? simply create a class that would call the target client sync or async mode, just like this

```
class ClientMethodCaller implements Runnable{
     ServerThread st;Object arg
     public ClientMethodCaller(ServerThread st,Object arg){this.st=st;this.arg=arg;}
     public void run () {
        st.forceToCall(arg);//signalling the client async
     }
}
```

and at the end, whenever you want to a client to run a specific method, just after finding the client(ServerThread) instance, call the target method by ClientMethodCaller

```
ServerThread st;//got the instance
new Thread(new ClientMethodCaller(st,"Hello!")).start();
```

and the final word, this is not good, running a thread for any client logins, IF the program, is not small and the number of users are to much.
also check [this tutorial](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html) too, would help